# Inserting a currency into SQL database

Tags: python, sql

Using sqlite and PyQt5 I am trying to insert currency values into a database of items.

Item Name -- Item Amount

The format should be: X.XX

The important part here is I want every value inserted into the sqlite database to show and have a value for up to 2 decimal places after the dollar amount. (I've also heard 4 decimal places can be good and helps rounding errors, I'm open to this as  well)

No matter what I do, if my dollar value has no cents ($X.00) it gets inserted into the database as "X".

I am using designer so I don't have specific code for my widget (of which I'm using the double spinbox), so here is a picture of the setup of that widget: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3kgl.jpg

Here is the database structure:

```sql
c.execute("CREATE TABLE items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name text, type bit, category text, date text, amount decimal(19,4), importance tinyint, notes text)")
```

So the amount column is a decimal(19,4) datatype.

To get the value of the double spinbox:

```py
amount = self.item_amount.value()

item = [name, group, category, date, amount, importance, notes]
```

Then it gets inserted into the database.

```sql
c.execute('INSERT INTO items (name, type, category, date, amount, importance, notes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', item)
```

No error messages are obtained, but my values are inserted into the database with no decimal places if it's an even dollar amount (i.e. 200.00 is stored as 200).

Comment: Try use float instead of Decimal?

Comment: I'm not sure how the float(n) datatype in SQL works. What would I use? float(2)?

Comment: The syntax for the command is `Float(M, D)`
where M is the total number of digits and D is the number of digits after the decimal point. In practical terms, float(6,5) would look like 9.9999. There are 6 digits in total (1+5), the 5 stating how many numbers after the decimal.

Comment: But what if I don't know how many digits to use? Should I just pick something like, say 1000000.00? (This is for personal transactions) So, float(9,2)?

Comment: @Robert Although in your project you use PyQt5 in your current problem has nothing to do.

Comment: By the way due to rounding errors that can occur in some databases most of the time currency is not stored in decimal format but in integer format then it is divided by 100 when pulled out and sent to be displayed

Comment: Dennis's solution is a decent approach a lot of the time, unless you deal with fractions of a cent then it's just weird and provides no benefit. Otherwise decimal/numeric is often preferred for currency. In this case `decimal` is probably the most sane data type to use here.

Comment: @DennisJensen You can also store dollars and cents and separate integers. This is often better as you don't lose fractions of a cent.

Comment: @tsturzl Yes you can use two fields to hold a single element of data but that usually is more work (and prone to errors) than storing a single value that you multiply by 100, 1000, 10000 prior to saving (which can sometimes be handled by the database itself) then divide by that same like amount (which again can sometimes be handled by the database) when it is queried back out.  The precision of the currency value is really just dependent upon the multiplier/divisor you are using -- very simple very straight forward and very accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply just how the number is represented. If you have no decimals there is no need to represent 200 as 200.00(as far as SQLite is concerned), if you had 200.11 it should give you exactly that number back. In your case you need to have your UI component pad the decimals for you or pad them yourself. In your cause it also seems like `decimal(19,4)` might not be what you want(I could be wrong here), you're essentially saying that you want 19 digits with 4 decimal places, but it seems like you're expecting your UI component to show 2 decimal places. Now a lot of people do track fractions of a cent for currency, in which case I understand wanting to store that precision, however then I'd also make sure you're representing that same level of precision in your UI.

Simply put your getting an expected result, regardless of the type you use you'll always query back `200` if you insert `200.00`. If it's being represented as `200` in your UI then you'll probably want to explore the specific toolkit you're using to pad your decimals.

In python you can pad decimals pretty easily

```
format(value, '.2f')
```

However it's very important to understand that this will always return a string. There is likely a way to handle this formatting in your UI toolkit.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200859/discussion-on-answer-by-tsturzl-inserting-a-currency-into-sql-database).